# How to do self join in query builder no eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-query-builder

Having hard time to do self join with query builder but getting unexpected results or query while using `toSql()` or `get()`, please don't suggest eloquent, just query builder with raw query.

Trying to get all child menus followed by their parent.
Id column also required

```
$users = DB::table('all_menus as A all_menus as B')
->select(DB::raw('A.menu_name__v1 As menu_name_parent, B.menu_name__v1 As menu_name_child'))
->where('A.id', '=' 'B.parent_menu_id__v1')
->toSql();
```

Comment: could you try join...

Comment: just use `join()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`join()` method supports to define an alias name, so you can self join with alias name like this query:

```php
$users = DB::table('all_menus as A')
           ->join('all_menus as B', 'A.id', '=', 'B.parent_menu_id__v1')
           ->select('A.menu_name__v1 AS menu_name_parent', 'B.menu_name__v1 AS menu_name_child')
           ->toSql();
```